# How to initialize the contents of a new object

Tags: perl

How do I set the initial values? This is what I did, but I'm not getting correct output.

```
sub new
{

    my $class=shift;
    my $self={
        Color => 0,
        Cost => 0,
        Wheels => 0,
        CC => 0,
        RegNo => 0,
        TopSpeed => 0,
        CurrentSpeed => 0,
        Angle => 0,
    };

    bless $self,$class;
    return $self;
}
```

IN .pl file, I created the object like this:

My `$obj=new vehicle();`
Then when I called a function that displays the variables, it gives me null.

Comment: Don't instantiate like that. Use `my $obj  = vehicle -> new();` And turn on strict and warnings, as I'm pretty sure `new vehicle()` won't work properly, because the latter isn't a method, it's a class.

Comment: Unfortunately, `new vehicle()` works just fine. But it's not recommended because it can be rather fragile. `vehicle->new()` is a much better idea.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the bits of code you have shown. Please publish the whole .pm file

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot missing from your example code. Let's suppose that you have this

(Note that, although it will work, this code is **wrong** because it uses an all-lowercase package name. Such identifiers are reserved for *Perl pragmas* like `strict`, `warnings`, `open`, `feature` etc.)

#### vehicle.pm

```
package vehicle;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {

    my $class = shift;

    my $self = {
        Color        => 0,
        Cost         => 0,
        Wheels       => 0,
        CC           => 0,
        RegNo        => 0,
        TopSpeed     => 0,
        CurrentSpeed => 0,
        Angle        => 0,
    };

    bless $self, $class;
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use vehicle;

my $obj = new vehicle();

use Data::Dump;
dd $obj;
```

Then the output is what you presumably expect

```
bless({
  Angle        => 0,
  CC           => 0,
  Color        => 0,
  Cost         => 0,
  CurrentSpeed => 0,
  RegNo        => 0,
  TopSpeed     => 0,
  Wheels       => 0,
}, "vehicle")
```

But there are many things that you could have got wrong on the way. Most likely you have named the package differently from its file name. The package name ***must*** match the `use` statement, and the file must be called `<package name>.pm`

Note that you should properly use CamelCase for the package and its file name, so here it would be `package Vehicle` and in a file called `Vehicle.pm`, and you would `use Vehicle` in the code that requires it

It's impossible to see the exact problem unless you show all of your module file

---

#### Update

The form `my $object = new Class()` is called ***indirect object syntax***. It is documented in [perldoc perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Invoking-Class-Methods) where it says

> **Outside of the file handle case, use of this syntax is discouraged as it can confuse the Perl interpreter. See below for more details.**

The reference to "the file handle case" refers to `print FILEHANDLE LIST`, which is such common usage that it cannot be deprecated. It is equivalent to `FILEHANDLE->print LIST` where `FILEHANDLE` is an [`IO::Handle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Handle) object

Nevertheless, `new CLASS LIST` and `new OBJECT LIST` are otherwise inadvisable, and `perlobj` identifies the reasons. Even though it may look neater to you that way, and more like other languages you have used, You should stick to `CLASS->new LIST` and `OBJECT->new LIST`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure as you don't show us the function you use to display the attributes. But this works (with minimal stylistic changes from your code):

```
# In Vehicle.pm
package Vehicle;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {

  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {
        Color => 0,
        Cost => 0,
        Wheels => 0,
        CC => 0,
        RegNo => 0,
        TopSpeed => 0,
        CurrentSpeed => 0,
        Angle => 0,
  };

  bless $self,$class;
  return $self;
}

sub current_speed {
  return shift->{CurrentSpeed};
}

1;
```

And in your program (which I've called `vehicle`):

```
# In vehicle
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Vehicle;

my $v = Vehicle->new;

say $v->current_speed;
```

Then, running `vehicle`:

```
$ perl vehicle
0
```

Which seems correct.

Comment: Is that suppose to be two separate source files?

Comment: Yeah. I didn't realise the SO Markdown parser would run them together like that. Fixed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! thanks. And when you say *"Then, running `vehicle`"*, is `vehicle` the name of the main Perl program?

Comment: If you want to publish two consecutive unrelated code blocks without any intervening narrative then just add an HTML comment `<!-- -->` and you will get a vertical whitespace gap